# merging columns data into string -- sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have following data in one table

[image]

I tried a lot but remain unsucessful,

What I want to achieve is following

[image]

**UPDATE** THERE CAN BE ANY NUMBER OF ATTCODE, MEANS I DONT KNOW HOW MANY ATTCODE CAN BE THERE

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server aggregate string concatenation"  or "SQL Server group_concat".

Comment: So, did you try my solution?

Answer (score 3):

Although aggregate string concatenation is the most general method, if you only have two values per `empid`, you could do:

```
select empid,
       (min(attcode + ':' + cast(count as varchar(255)) + ' & ' +
        max(attcode + ':' + cast(count as varchar(255))
       ) as str
from t
group by empid;
```

This is not a general solution but it might solve your problem if you have example two values for each group.

Comment: THERE CAN BE ANY NUMBER OF ATTCODE

Comment: Then @gofr1's solution is better for your problem.  I just proposed this as a possible simplification, given the data in the question.

Answer (score 1):

That will work for any number of ATTCodes:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'CL', 10),
(1, 'SL', 20),
(2, 'CL', 9),
(2, 'SL', 2)) as t(EmpId, ATTCode, [Count])
)

select DISTINCT  c.EmpId,
        REPLACE(STUFF((SELECT ',' + ATTCode +':'+CAST([Count] as nvarchar(5)) 
        FROM cte s
        WHERE s.EmpId = c.EmpId
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''),',',' & ') as [Str]
from cte c
```

Result:

```
EmpId       Str
----------- ----------------
1           CL:10 & SL:20
2           CL:9 & SL:2

(2 row(s) affected)
```